How should I interpret this conflict of "overrideModeDefault" and actual value in my applicationHost.Config?
I'm reviewing ASVS with my application in mind. Many of the questions I can answer, many are a learning experience -- this is one such experience. I'm on item V4.3.2 - Verify that directory browsing is disabled unless deliberately desired. Additionally, applications should not allow discovery or disclosure of file or directory metadata, such as Thumbs.db, .DS_Store, .git or .svn folders.
This is probably really simple, but I want to ensure I understand what I'm reading in the applicationhost.config file in my source code.
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
      <section name="directoryBrowse" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Does the above say "In the absence of a specified state, assume allow on DirectoryBrowse" but also, it's specified to be false, so despite the overrideModeDefault, it's still false?
